# how I return smallest three numbers from the first array to new array?

Tags: javascript

```js
let years = [1, 4, 2, 7, 3, 9, 5];
let k = 3; // new array of three the smallest nums from the first array

function removedIntegers(arr) {
  let sortedArr = arr.sort();
  let j = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < sortedArr.length; i++) {
    if (sortedArr[i] != sortedArr[i + 1]) {
      return Element.years > k;
      //   j.push(sortedArr[i]);
    }
  }
  return j;
}

console.log(removedIntegers(years))
```

Comment: And the problem with your code is ...?

Comment: Why are you returning the value of the comparison?

Comment: What is `Element`? It looks like you took that line from code that uses `filter()`, which is totally unrelated to this question.

Comment: Sort the array, then return `sortedArr.slice(0, 3)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let years = [1, 4, 2, 7, 3, 9, 5];

function removedIntegers(arr) {
  let sortedArr = arr.sort().slice(0,3);
  console.log(sortedArr)
}
```